# NSNotification selector getting called twice

Tags: ios

I have a code structure like this

```
- (id) init {
        ...
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(test) name:@"test"  object:nil];
}

- (void) test
{
  NSLog(@"test");     // test is printed twice
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue, ^{
    [self refresh];
  })
}

- (void)refresh
{
  ...
}
```

However, following code outputs "test" only once

```
- (void) test
{
  NSLog(@"test");     // test is printed only once
  [self refresh];
}
```

I am not able to understand why its printed twice with code above and only once with the code below

Comment: From where did you post the notification?

Comment: You replaced first method with second? Or the second method is in another class? May be that class have more instances alive.

Comment: There was a race condition I was dealing with. My notification handler was configured in a wrong view. I can not accept any answer but I have upvoted the response(s) as it helped me debug the issue

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1: The first thing is to check if the notification itself is posted twice.

Solution 2: Even if the notification is posted only once, the action will be called as many times you've added the observer for the notification (no matter the notification is same or not). For example, the following two lines will register the observer(self) for the same notification(aSelector) twice.

Solution 3: If you are not sure whether you have already added the observer or not, you can simply do the following. This will make sure that the observer is added only once.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"test" object:nil];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(test) name:@"test"  object:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding a breakpoint on your NSLog and back trace the calls to your method using your Debug navigator.

If it does not help, we would like to see where are you posting the notification from.